# Can't avoid field label to be echoed

Tags: cakephp

I've been creating an app preparing it already to be internationalized. But when I try to do this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('end_date', array('label' => __('End Date'), 'dateFormat' => 'DMY', 'minYear' => date('Y'), 'type' => 'text'));\
```

It echoes two "End Date". I tried disabling label by setting it to null, but didn't work either. :(

How can I avoid this to happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of NULL, try setting it to false:

```
'label' => false
```

You can also set ALL inputs of a form to default to `'label'=>false` by using:

```
'inputDefaults'=> array('label'=>false)
```

as an option of your form

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, the `__()` function echoes its value by default instead of returning it. That's why you were seeing the label displayed twice. It was being displayed once because that's the value that the field name resolves to automagically. It was being displayed the second time by the `__()` method. In other words, your `label` option wasn't really overriding the automatic label.

```
echo $this->Form->input(
  'end_date', 
  array(
    'label' => __('Modified End Date Label', true), # note the "true" argument
    'dateFormat' => 'DMY', 
    'minYear' => date('Y'), 
    'type' => 'text'
  )
);
```

For more, see the [__ documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/file/cake/basics.php#function-__).